# AWS Alexa SKill - AWS lambda API error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Deployed AWS alexa module using AWS lambda deploy.

my zip file contains.
package.json
package-lock.json
node_modules
index.js

When i tested my aws lambda function, it failed with below. I am using amazon alexa API.

function call to voice output is  this.emit('some text');

2017-08-14T06:39:47.468Z    5af7ac74-80bb-11e7-9b7e-5b3b7c9fd513    TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at /var/task/index.js:62:31

Comment: Please paste the code of index.js.

Comment: And btw it's this.emit(':tell', 'Hello World')

Comment: also please point out which library are you using to process the requests. If it is the alexa-sdk or some other third party one you found on npm

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed 'alexa-sdk' package in your node module (npm install --save alexa-sdk). If you already installed that Please share code of index.js.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't upload the libraries in the lambda funcition, if you are using node, you have to upload the `node_modules`

You should access lambda folder and run "yarn" or "npm install" depending on which one you are using.